# Python-twisted: Preventing buffering between tcp reader and web resource

Tags: python, twisted, gstreamer

I am trying to implement an MJPEG server using a Twisted web.Resource which
gets its data by reading from an upstream gstreamer process which is itself
writing MJPEG data to TCP port localhost:9999. I have something like this
right now:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol, defer
from twisted.web import server, resource

class MJpegResource(resource.Resource):
    def __init__(self, queues):
        self.queues = queues

    @defer.inlineCallbacks
    def deferredRenderer(self, request):
        q = defer.DeferredQueue()
        self.queues.append([q, request])
        while True:
            yield q.get()

    def render_GET(self, request):
        request.setHeader("content-type", 'multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=--spionisto')
        self.deferredRenderer(request)
        return server.NOT_DONE_YET

class JpegStreamReader(protocol.Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        for (q, req) in self.factory.queues:
            req.write(data)
            q.put('')

root = File('web')
root.putChild('stream.mjpeg', MJpegResource(queues))

factory = protocol.Factory()
factory.protocol = JpegStreamReader
factory.queues = queues
reactor.listenTCP(9999, factory)

site = server.Site(root)
reactor.listenTCP(80, site)

# spawn gstreamer process which writes to port 9999.
# The gstream process is launched using:
# gst-launch-1.0 -v \
#     v4l2src device=/dev/video0 \
#         ! video/x-raw,framerate=15/1, width=640, height=480 \
#         ! jpegenc \
#         ! multipartmux boundary=spionisto \
#         ! tcpclientsink host=127.0.0.1 port=9999 \

reactor.run()
```

So something like:

```
gstreamer --> JpegStreamReader --> MJpegResource
```

This works OK, but I have found that occassionally, the video on the
browser falls far behind what is "live" (by as much as 30-40 seconds
sometimes). As soon as I refresh the browser, the MJPEG stream jumps back
to being "live". So my suspicion is that the JpegStreamReader is not able
to write to the TCP socket corresponding to web.http.Request as fast as
gstreamer is filling up the TCP socket 9999 and things are getting buffered
on the input queue to the JpegStreamReader.

Since the stream is supposed to be "live", I am OK with dropping frames to
bring back the video to live. However, I am not sure how to even detect
that the JpegStreamReader is falling behind etc? Any suggestions on how to
make this pipeline behave more like a live-stream?

If there's fundamentally another architecture for doing this, suggestions
would be greatly appreciated as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register a producer on the `Request` object.  It will have its `pauseProducing` method called when the write buffer of that `Request` is full.  When room becomes available, it will have its `resumeProducing` method call.

You can use this information to drop frames that may not be delivered in a timely fashion.  However, you will have to actually identify frames in your server (currently you only have a `dataReceived` method that passes data through as a stream with no idea where frames begin or end).  This also has the problem that buffer fullness is possibly a very lagging indicator of delays in the stream.  And if the bottleneck in the system isn't in between reading data from gstreamer and writing it to the requests, adding backpressure sensitivity to this part of the program isn't going to help.

Comment: Thank you very much! I just implemented your suggestion and I think it should actually solve my problem. I've been playing with the video stream for a while now and I see the expected dropped frame when there is extra network activity in the internal network. 

The final solution also consists of only responding to resumeProducing with a one second delay.

For the sake of posterity, I would like to include the code I finally came up with. Is the convention to put this in a separate answer by myself or put it into a comment. If a separate answer should I accept that answer or this one?

Answer (score 2):

This is the final solution which implements Jean-Paul Calerone's
suggestion. Notice that now we have a JpegProducer class which implements
the PushProducer interface. When requested to pause, it sets a flag. This
enables the TCP stream reader (JpegStreamReader) to not push frames into
that particular producer if it is clogged. Per Jean-Paul's suggestion, I
also had to break up the multi-part MJPEG stream into chunks so that we
always drop frames without breaking the MJPEG output format.

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol, defer, interfaces
from twisted.web import server, resource
from zope.interface import implementer

class MJpegResource(resource.Resource):
    def __init__(self, queues):
        self.queues = queues

    def setupProducer(self, request):
        producer = JpegProducer(request)
        request.notifyFinish().addErrback(self._responseFailed, producer)
        request.registerProducer(producer, True)

        self.queues.append(producer)

    def _responseFailed(self, err, producer):
        producer.stopProducing()

    def render_GET(self, request):
        request.setHeader("content-type", 'multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=--spionisto')
        self.setupProducer(request)
        return server.NOT_DONE_YET

@implementer(interfaces.IPushProducer)
class JpegProducer(object):
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.request = request
        self.isPaused = False
        self.isStopped = False
        self.delayedCall = None

    def cancelCall(self):
        if self.delayedCall:
            self.delayedCall.cancel()
            self.delayedCall = None

    def pauseProducing(self):
        self.isPaused = True
        self.cancelCall()

    def resetPausedFlag(self):
        self.isPaused = False
        self.delayedCall = None

    def resumeProducing(self):
        # calling self.cancelCall is defensive. We should not really get
        # called with multiple resumeProducing calls without any
        # pauseProducing in the middle.
        self.cancelCall()
        self.delayedCall = reactor.callLater(1, self.resetPausedFlag)
        log('producer is requesting to be resumed')

    def stopProducing(self):
        self.isPaused = True
        self.isStopped = True
        log('producer is requesting to be stopped')

MJPEG_SEP = '--spionisto\r\n'

class JpegStreamReader(protocol.Protocol):
    def __init__(self):
        self.tnow = None

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.data = ''
        self.tnow = datetime.now()

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.data += data

        chunks = self.data.rsplit(MJPEG_SEP, 1)

        dataToSend = ''
        if len(chunks) == 2:
            dataToSend = chunks[0] + MJPEG_SEP

        self.data = chunks[-1]

        for producer in self.factory.queues:
            if (not producer.isPaused):
                producer.request.write(dataToSend)
```